# подскажите в чем проблема

Tags: php, javascript

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

у меня три кнопки с разним data-id-news а вот в консоль почемуто все время только 3 показевает ксли сделать вот так

```
$('.read-more').bind('click', function(){

    var id_news = $('.full-news').attr('data-id-news');
    console.log(id_news);
});
```

Comment: var id_news = $(this).attr('data-id-news');

Comment: Если ответ помог - то можно ставить галочку напротив ответа ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Ты сам пишешь `$('.full-news')` - это не есть отношение к конкретному блоку. К конкретному селектору будет относить `this`, который указывает на контекст, на отношение, на то, откуда происходит вызов в данный момент. То есть примерно так:

```
$('.read-more').bind('click', function(){

    var id_news = $(this).attr('data-id-news'); // $(this).data().idNews; | $(this).data('idNews')
    console.log(id_news);
});
```